# Simple PHP If Statement Not Acting As Expected

Tags: php

This is a simple year validation that should check if the year is between 1900 and the current year. If the year is valid it should be displayed as the input's value.

```
    if(!empty($year) && $year >= 1900 || !empty($year) && $year <= date('Y')){
 $yearHolder = 'value="'.$year.'"';
}else{
$yearHolder = 'placeholder="Year"';
}
```

The problem I'm having is that the statement does not work, and passes any numbers through.

Comment: Because `||` needs to be and AND operator. Right now in other words your `$year` can be either bigger than 1900 or just less than 2015. So long story short: `if(!empty($year) && $year >= 1900 && $year <= date("Y"))` (<- Also side note: Since the function call `date` is at the end it only gets called if all other conditions are already TRUE)

Comment: Change your condition as :if(!empty($year) && $year >= 1900 && $year <= date('Y'))

Comment: @nickyb You're welcome. Also as I said, the last thing, that you have the function call `date()` at the end is only clever, since PHP has [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this.

```
if(!empty($year) && $year >= 1900 && $year <= date('Y')){
    $yearHolder = 'value="'.$year.'"';
}else{
    $yearHolder = 'placeholder="Year"';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if(!empty($year) && $year >= 1900 && $year <= date('Y')){
```

No need to check if `$year` is empty twice and make them all ANDs.

Answer (score 0):

To be sure about conditions, place it separately.

```
if(!empty($year))
{
    if ($year >= 1900 && $year <= date('Y'))
    {
        $yearHolder = 'value="'.$year.'"';
    }else{
        $yearHolder = 'placeholder="Year"';
    }
} else {
    echo "Year is empty";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to change your middle [`||` OR condition](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.logical.php) to and AND condition, to get your logic, which you want. Right now in other words your condition is:

> IF `$year` is NOT empty AND `$year` is either bigger than 1900 **OR** less than 2015

But what you want is:

> IF `$year` is NOT empty AND `$year` is either bigger than 1900 **AND** less than 2015

So your if statement should look something like this:

```
if(!empty($year) && $year >= 1900 && $year <= date("Y"))
```

Also note, that the function call `date()` is at the end, which makes it only execute, if the other two pieces in the condition are TRUE. That is because PHP has [short circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Answer (score 0):

Consolidating other suggestions, you could try something like this:

```
if (!empty($year) && $year >= 1900 && $year <= date('Y')) {
    $yearHolder = 'value="' . $year . '"';
} else {
    $yearHolder = 'placeholder="Year"';
}
```

This removes the redundant check for empty values, corrects your || to an &&